# Start 'tmux' before Vim. The X Window system is required to run R in an external terminal

Tags: r, vim

I am using a previous version of `Vim-R-Plugin` and pretty comfortable about its settings. Recently I upgraded the Linux system and got message never before `"Start 'tmux' before Vim. The X Window system is required to run R in an external terminal."`. The issue is, if I start tmux manually, the vim background were also changed weirdly and further `,rc` will start a R console in a split window rather than a new window. Does somebody know the reasons and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to styles and handling of tmux 'emulated terminal'.
At first try to simply run

```
tmux -2
```

If it does not help try add in ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: If you will struggle through that keys which worked previously stopped working <S-F1> for example then try:
set -g xterm-keys on

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It's very helpful. I bet you are using Vim-R-pluggin? Now I can initiate R console by `,rf` but the console is opened at the bottom of the same terminal, I am wondering whether you happen to know how to make it open from a separate terminal or open it from right vertically would be fine too (I have `set splitright` in .vimrc).

Comment: Unfortunatly no, but I would search :h vim-r-plugin There should be an option